# Pushing to a Docker registry that is not directly exposed to the internet

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker with a registry on an on-premise device where I'm not allowed to open up for any inbound connections. This means that I can't directly push images to my registry from the outside.

I am allowed to initiate outbound connections.

Is there any way to push an image with this limitation? The only workaround I have found is to save the image as a tar file on the server, download it from my device and then load + push it into the registry.

Comment: Is opening an SSH tunnel possible? I.e. from "inside" ssh to a server "outside", having that server listening on a port which is then forwarded to your registry.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting approach, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: This [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/#remote-port-forwarding) describes the approach. What you would need is a machine which is located "outside" that can be reached via ssh from "inside". you would login to that machine (from inside to outside) via a command line similar to `ssh -R 5555:internal.server.name:5000 ...` This would forward port 5555 of your outside machine to port 5000 of the internal machine. You would access your registry from outside as `outside.server.name:5555` (port numbers can be changed of course)